Optimization of Convolution Double Integral
I am looking to find the optimal solution to the following double integral:
$$\min_{\pi: \int \pi(x)=1} \int^{a}_{-a} \int^a_{-a} \exp(-(x-y)^2) \pi(x)\pi(y) \;dx\;dy $$
I have been trying to use Fourier Transform without much success. Clearly we can transform the original problem into:
$$\min_{\pi': \int \pi'(x)=1, \;\pi'(x)=0\;\forall |x|>a} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \exp(-(x-y)^2) \pi'(x)\pi'(y) \;dx\;dy $$
Then by fourier transform, this can be equivalently formulated as:
$$\min_{\pi': \hat{\pi}'(0)=1,???} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \sqrt{\pi} e^{-\pi^2k^2}|\hat{\pi}'(k)|^2 \;dk $$
It seems like I should take $\hat{\pi}'(k)$to be the point function where $\hat{\pi}'(0)=1$ and 0 everywhere, but I am not sure how the compactness condition transforms over into the fourier space. Intuitively, I expect the optimal solution for $\pi(x)$ to concentrate at the edges of $a$ and $-a$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Did you already explore a Lagrange multiplier formulation?

The Paley-Wiener theorem characterizes the Fourier transforms of compactly supported functions but I doubt that will be useful in this optimization framework

@Aruralreader I did, you end up with the equation $$\int \exp(-(x-y)^2)\pi(y) dy=C$$ for some constant C for all x if and only if the first-order condition for the functional does hold at optimality, which I didnt know how to proceed from there either.
